# Adoquery1: CommandText does not return a result set

Tags: sql, delphi

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin    
  ADOQuery1.close;    
  ADOQuery1.SQL.text:='insert into veresiye (product,price,piece,total) 
                                     VALUES (:par0,:par1,:par2,:par3)';    
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('par0').Value:=Edit1.Text;    
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('par1').Value:=Edit2.Text;    
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('par2').Value:=Edit3.Text;    
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('par3').Value:=Edit4.Text;    
  ADOQuery1.Open;    
  ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
end;
```

and I get this error message:

> Adoquery1: CommandText does not return a result set

Why do I get this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Because of 'ADOQuery1.Open'.Remove it.

Comment: yes, you should use Open (you will be able to get DataSet result) or ExecSQL (no DataSet result)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion I removed adoquery1.open but db grid show nothing happen. But I look  to table last change appear I show this  in   youtube video

Comment: if you want to show data in grid, use `select ... from  veresiye`... '`Open`

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXritAB00sc&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Thanks Val Marino  worked !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Call ExecSQL to execute the SQL statement currently assigned to the
>   SQL property. **Use ExecSQL to execute queries that do not return a
>   cursor to data (such as INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, and CREATE TABLE).**
>
> ExecSQL returns an integer value reflecting the number of rows
>   affected by the executed SQL statement. Note: **For SELECT statements,
>   call Open instead of ExecSQL or set the Active property to true**. To
>   speed performance, an application should ordinarily prepare the query
>   by setting the Prepared property to true before calling ExecSQL for
>   the first time.

Source : http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ADODB_TADOQuery_ExecSQL.html

To insert values in table use :

```
  ADOQuery1.close;    
  ADOQuery1.SQL.text:='insert into veresiye (product,price,piece,total) 
                                     VALUES (:par0,:par1,:par2,:par3)';    
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('par0').Value:=Edit1.Text;    
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('par1').Value:=Edit2.Text;    
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('par2').Value:=Edit3.Text;    
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('par3').Value:=Edit4.Text;     
  ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

To get values from table use:

```
  ADOQuery1.close;    
  ADOQuery1.SQL.text:='select * from veresiye';       
  ADOQuery1.Open;
```

Answer (score 5):

You should simply remove the call to

```
ADOQuery1.Open;
```

`Open` is used to open the dataset returned by the query.  This is also equivalent to setting `ADOQuery1.Active := true`.  In this case, an `INSERT` statement does not return a dataset so there is nothing to open.

`ExecSQL` is used to execute statements that do not return a result dataset so that is all you need to use here.

Answer (score 1):

To insert values in table :

```
ADOQuery1.Close;
ADOQuery1.SQL.text:='insert into veresiye (product,price,piece,total) 
                                 VALUES (:par0,:par1,:par2,:par3)';
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('par0').Value:=Edit1.Text;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('par1').Value:=Edit2.Text;    
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('par2').Value:=Edit3.Text;    
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('par3').Value:=Edit4.Text;     
Try 
  ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
except on E: Exception do
  MessageDlg(E.Message,mtError,[mbOK],0);
End;
```